# If $ f _p(x)=1+x+x^2+ \cdots +x^{p-1} $ where $p$ is prime number, $e$ is any positive integer.

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Show that   $f_p (x^{p^{e-1}})$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know it is obviously true for $ p=2$. Please suggest me any hints

Comment: Hint: Try using Eisenstein's criterion and the binomial theorem.

Comment: Would you mind formatting the formula correctly, it does not display clearly for me, and from the code I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Andreas ,I am beggner in latex, I want to understand it is f_{p}(x^p^(e-1))

Comment: It was indeed, it's fixed now, thanks.

Comment: You start your question from the title is just like the first sentence of a book start from its cover...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof follows from:

- The [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), $\Phi_n(x)$, are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.
- $f_p(x^{p^{e-1}})=\Phi_{p^e}(x).$
  Proof:
  Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n^{th}$ primitive root of unity, $\zeta_n=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$ and let $0\leq m \leq p-1 $.
   
  The ${p^{e-1}}^{th}$ roots of $\zeta_p^{m}\in\mathbb C$ are $\exp{\left(\frac{2k\pi i}{p^{e-1}}+\frac{2m \pi i}{p^e}\right)}, \ k=0,1,2,\ldots p^{e-1}-1$ or equivalently $\zeta^{kp+m}_{p^e}, \ k=0,1,\ldots,p^{e-1}-1$. Therefore \begin{align}x^{p^{e-1}}-\zeta_p^{m}=(x-\zeta^m_{p^e})(x-\zeta^{p+m}_{p^e})(x-\zeta^{2p+m}_{p^e})\ldots (x-\zeta^{(p^{e-1}-1)p+m}_{p^e}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\end{align}
  Multiplying the previous by parts for $m=0,1,\ldots,p-1$ we obtain $$\Phi_p(x^{p^{e-1}})=f_p(x^{p^{e-1}})=\Phi_{p^e}(x).$$

Comment: ,My question is to prove irreducibility of the function $f_p (x^p^(e-1))$

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak Do you mean $f_p\left(x^{p^{e-1}}\right)?$

Comment: ,Yes, my question is that, but I can not understand your logic, can you help me to clear it?

Comment: Many many thanks to you

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak: Maybe [this](http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/cyclotomic_polynomials.pdf) will help you.